# MSSQL - Select distinct products that are found in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Suppose I have the following combinations in my dataset:

```
**ProductA**            **ProductB**
  Apple                   Banana
  Apple                   Orange
  Apple                   Pear
  Banana                  Orange
  Banana                  Pear
  Orange                  Pear
```

How would I return a complete list of unique products in a single column? Desired output below:

```
**Products**
Apple
Banana
Orange
Pear
```

If I do select distinct, I obviously won't get the pear because it's not included in column ProductA.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Is this a homework problem ?

Comment: Ha- No this isn't homework.  I dumbed down the product names to make it easy to follow.

Comment: select fruits from productA UNION select fruits from productB

Comment: Simple union works @user1765523

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can UNION them together as a single column:

```
SELECT  ProductA AS Products
FROM    tablename
UNION
SELECT  ProductB
FROM    tablename;
```

Comment: I think you won't need the DISTINCT since UNION would return distinct values for you.

Comment: yeah i agree with @Ala simple union works why to use Derived table and Distinct if you have really required the same output .By using Distinct and Derived table then more lookup's will be done on table and query cost will be increased..just check with execution plan